# jQuery reset one() method, after being called

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

I'm trying to reset one() after its been executed.

Here is my html:

```
<textarea name="comment"> Write comment...</textarea>
<div id="buttons" style="display:none">
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
  <button id="cancel"></button>
</div>
```

Here is the first part that transforms text area into  wysiwyg:

```
$('textarea[name=comment]').one("click", function() {
    $(this).editor();
    $("#buttons").show();   
});
```

and here is the part that resets all:

```
$('#cancel').click(function() {
    $('textarea[name=comment]').editor('destroy');
    $("#buttons").hide();   
});
```

First part works fine, `textarea` gets converted into editor, and `buttons` are visible, now second part, removes editor and hides `buttons`, but clicking again on `textarea`, nothing nothing happens due to `one()`.

Comment: You need to call `.one()` again. Like the name implies, it only fires once, then it goes away forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `.one()` if you want it to fire multiple times. If you want the behavior to be conditional, write that explicitly into the code.

```
$('textarea[name=comment]').on("click", function() {
    var editor_disabled = $(this).data("editor-disabled");
    if (!editor_disabled) {
        $(this).editor();
        $("#buttons").show();
        $(this).data("editor-disabled", true); // disable until we cancel
    }
});

$('#cancel').click(function() {
    $('textarea[name=comment]').editor('destroy');
    $("#buttons").hide();
    $('textarea[name=comment]').data("editor-disabled", false); // re-enable
});
```

Comment: I'm getting error in firebug : ReferenceError: enable_editor is not defined

Comment: Should be `editor_disabled`. I forgot to fix that when editing.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out, also last line $(this).data("editor-disabled", false); // re-enable should be  $('textarea[name=comment]').data("editor-disabled", false); // re-enable

Comment: Sorry about that. I was switching from a global variable to `.data()`, didn't realize the disconnect between the two buttons.

Answer (score 1):

`one()` only fires once then goes away, so you'll have to subscribe to the event again in your cancel click handler. You can wrap it in a function to avoid repeating yourself:

```
function registerCommentClick() {
    $('textarea[name=comment]').one("click", function() {
        $(this).editor();
        $("#buttons").show();   
    });
}

registerCommentClick();

$('#cancel').click(function() {
    $('textarea[name=comment]').editor('destroy');
    $("#buttons").hide();

    registerCommentClick();   
});
```

Alternatively, don't use `one()` but instead use a flag or check for existence of an editor / your `#buttons`'s visibility.